# Audacity won't start after upgrade to Debian Sid (relocation error)

Tags: linux, debian, audacity

ever since I upgraded Debian stable to Debian sid I cannot start audacity. It gives me this error when I start from command line:

```
audacity: relocation error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwx_gtk2u_adv-3.0.so.0: 
symbol _ZThn696_N15wxComboCtrlBase9WriteTextERK8wxString version WXU_3.0 not
defined in file libwx_gtk2u_core-3.0.so.0 with link time reference
```

I still cannot find out how to fix this problem.

Comment: Wait for the new version, or report the bug, if no one did this before.

Answer (score 1):

`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwx_gtk2u_adv-3.0.so.0` is provided by the package `libwxgtk3.0-0v5` in Debian Stretch and Sid, but the two Debian repositories contain different versions [(3.0.2+dfsg-4 for Stretch, 3.0.4+dfsg-7 for Sid)](https://qa.debian.org/madison.php?package=libwxgtk3.0-0v5&table=debian).

Did you make sure to upgrade *all* packages when you switched from Stretch to Sid?

Keep in mind that Sid is the unstable distribution of Debian and thus ["subject to massive changes and in-place library updates"](https://www.debian.org/releases/sid/) that can lead to version mismatches like the one you're seeing here.
In those cases, it is usually best to wait until all packages of the dependency chain (here: Audacity and its libraries) have been updated to be consistent again. If you can't afford delays like this, then, frankly, Sid is not the right distribution for your use case.